# HTACCESS: Do a url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to use htaccess to do a url rewrite.
I would like the people to access the site in the browser using this:

```
http://exmaple.com/ladada
```

But the files are inside a subdomain:

```
http://ladada.exmaple.com
```

Would that be possible? People will access the site using the first link but in the backend it's being rewritten to the second link? Thank you so much!

Comment: I had posted an answer but deleted it because I misread the question. Is your subdomain pointing to the same server  or its on a diffent server?

Comment: Hi @starkeen, it's in the same server.

Answer (score 0):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) doc should help you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ladada\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/ladada/$1 [L,R=301]
```